# Positioning Objects at the same Elevation

Tags: three.js

I have an issue with the position of cubes in my application. When I set them all with the same size they are rendered properly on the same `Y` position as I defined: 
Example:

```
geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(50, 50, 50);
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 })
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
mesh.position.set(100, 0, 400); // I always set y as 0 because I want the cubes to be on the same level like buildings in a city
```

And I do the same for the next cubes, only changing the `X` and `Z` positions. 
However, when I create cubes with different sizes, which is my objective, as follows,

```
geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(50, 100, 50);
```

they appear on a different level in the final visualization on the browser, as shows the image:

https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/3678443/8651664/35574c18-2972-11e5-8c75-2612733ea595.png

Any ideas on how to solve this problem? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BoxGeometry` is centered on the origin. There are two solutions to translating the box so it sits on the XZ-plane.

**Option 1.** Translate the *geometry* so the bottom face of the box passes through the origin. You do that by translating the geometry up by half its height.

```
geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 50, 50, 50 );

geometry.translate( 0, 50 / 2, 0 );

mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
mesh.position.set( 100, 0, 400 );
```

**Option 2.** Translate the *mesh* by setting its position.

```
geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 50, 50, 50 );

mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
mesh.position.set( 100, 50 / 2, 400 );
```

The first option is likely preferable for your use case.

three.js r.92

Comment: Thank you, it worked well. Falk Thiele's solution also worked but this seemed more practical. :)

Comment: You can use one geometry for all your meshes. `geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 ); geometry.applyMatrix( ... );` Then set each mesh size with `mesh.scale.set( a, b, c );`

Answer (score 2):

The Position of the Objects is correct, they are placed where their center´s are. So your cube with `100` height in geometry extends `50` to the top and `50` to the bottom, its centroid is right in its "middle" at `0`.

You could set the y positions of your Cubes to `y + cube.geometry.parameters.height / 2` so every cube is aligned at one level (variable y).